# An inequality in martingale

Tags: probability, inequality, stochastic-processes, martingales

Suppose $X_n$ is a supermartingale,for $\lambda>0$ ,we have the following inequality:
$$\lambda\mathbb{P}(\inf_{n\leq k}X_n\leq-\lambda)\leq\int_{[\inf_{n\leq k }X_n\leq -\lambda]}(-X_k) \mathbb{dP}$$

I have tried  to prove:

Let $T=\inf\{n:X_n \leq-\lambda\}\wedge k$, so $T$ is a bounded stopping time.By OST:

$$\mathbb{E}[-X_0]\leq\mathbb{E}[-X_T]=\int_{[\inf_{n\leq k }X_n\leq -\lambda]}-X_T \mathbb{dP}+\int_{[\inf_{n\leq k }X_n> -\lambda]}-X_T \mathbb{dP}$$
$$\geq\lambda\mathbb{P}(\inf_{n\leq k }X_n\leq -\lambda)+\int_{[\inf_{n\leq k }X_n> -\lambda]}-X_k \mathbb{dP}$$

Then I don't know how to do next since the two inequalities are not consistent.

Comment: Apply any proof of Doob’s martingale maximal inequalities to the submartingale $-X$, for example [this one](http://fabricebaudoin.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/lecture-11-doobs-martingale-maximal-inequalities/).

Comment: @Did,thanks,but the textbook applied this inequality to prove Doob's inequality and the author omitted the proof.

Comment: @Did,Furthermore,you can't use the Doob's inequality to prove this one since this inequality is stronger than Doob's inequality(consider the interval of the integration).

Comment: Did you try to read the link in my comment?

Comment: @Did, Oh I'm sorry that I only read the title...

Comment: @Did,thanks,Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof of Doob’s martingale maximal inequalities applies to the submartingale $−X$, see for example [this one](http://fabricebaudoin.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/lecture-11-doobs-martingale-maximal-inequalities/).